# Drupal 8 Customize template content type form page

Tags: php, forms, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I am trying to customize a simple add form page.

My content type, created via admin interface, is very simple, it's got 4 fields I want to display.

But I want, in the future, to show more fields. And the maximum to be managed by the system.

I need to display in my form part 1 and part 2. Part 1 is "my account information", it has login and password fields. Part 2 is "my details", it has phone number, address fields.

My page :

```
My title

<form>
    <h1>my account</h1>
    <field>login</field>
    <field>password</field>

    <h1>my details</h1>
    <field>phone_number</field>
    <field>address</field>
    <button>add</submit>
</form>
```

Is there a way by the interface to make it ? (I think not)

For now I have created a new $suggestions via

```
function fiters_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)
{
  if (
    isset($variables['element']) 
    && isset($variables['element']['#type']) 
    && $variables['element']['#type'] == 'form' 
    && \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath() == '/node/add/inscription'
  ){
    $original_theme_hook = $variables['theme_hook_original'];
    $suggestions[] = $original_theme_hook . '__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']);
  }
}
```

I can create **'form--node-inscription-form.html.twig'**, in it I have

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ children }}
</form>
```

My goal would be to modify children and change it to

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  <h1>my account</h1>
  {{ form.login }}
  {{ form.password}}
  <h1>my details</h1>
  {{ form.address }}
  {{ form.phone }}
</form>
```

But it is not working, but ! (again) I found that you could add a file named **'node-inscription-form.html.twig'** and modify at your will... it crashed and asked for '.html.twig', and of course didn't find it.

I wanted something simple, that you could understand and modify quickly but it is hooking world !! I didn't want to create a module just for that...

Maybe I went too far (or not enough), anyone has a suggestion to find a way to display an easy custom form on /node/add/{content} ?

**Edit - the solution**

I hooked directly the form and changed the #theme, which is looking for a new template file with the same name.

I deleted **fiters_theme_suggestions_alter** function and added

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
*/
function fiters_form_node_inscription_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#theme'] = ['custom_node_inscription_form'];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */
function fiters_theme() {
  $themes['custom_node_inscription_form'] = [
   'render element' => 'form'
  ];

  return $themes;
}
```

I added a template with the name **custom-node-inscription-form.html.twig** in my **themes/fiters/template/form** folder

The name of my theme is **fiters**, so as mention in hook names, the template will be applied only on that theme.

Because you never do anything without sources : **[Create your own module with custom form](https://www.foreach.be/blog/how-manipulate-forms-drupal-8)**

(becareful a hook name has a typo in name in this source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x

In the alter you need to check if you are on the theme you desire: 
\Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();

And make the changes you want.

Hope I was helpful, please ask further questions if needed.

Comment: I saw this hook in my research that would be the extension of the form where I can access the formBuilder, but how can I modify the template via this hook ? How can I add custom HTML tags like <h1> and some <div> encapsulating the 2 fields but not the last 2 fields

Comment: Programmation when it is working it is like magic, I will never be tired to see it working, it makes me happy. Editing my post with the answer :) Thanks